# VB Net Update GUI from Thread in a different vb file

Tags: multithreading

First of all, I´ve been reading a lot about this but I don´t get the freaking answer anyway. I know I shouldnt be updating the UI from a thread but in this case I think is the only way.

My application sends emails, lots of them, let´s say 500, and to avoid overloading the app I am using a thread to process the information stored in a DDBB. Everything works fine, I am using delegates and I succeeded in sending them over the client, but I want the application to show a message in the MDI form label saying something like "Email sent to: blabla@gmail.com at 10:00:00" just to show the user that the process is running in the background...

My code is simple:

---

### - from MDI:

BulkThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ProcessBulkList))

BulkThread.Start()

---

### - From the module that contains ProcessBulkList:

Public Delegate Sub MySubPara(ByVal p As String)

Public sub ProcessBulkList ()

```
   Dim DelegateMDI As MySubPara = New MySubPara(AddressOf MostrarEnMDI)

   DelegateMDI.Invoke("example@gmail.com")
```

End Sub

Public Sub MostrarEnMDI(para As String)

```
    MDI.LabelSMS.Text = "Message sent to: " & para & " at " & GetTime()
    MDI.Refresh()
```

End Sub

Of course in ProcessBulkList function there are more delegates and stuff and everything works perfect but this call, doesnt show anything on the MDI form...Probably the MDI that I am using is a copy of the original one, but why???? because using invoke from a thread should use the SendMessage function that calls the queue of elements in the Main thread, isnt it??

Answer (score 1):

In your thread ( in a true thread must pass the origional form can show you if you need that example ) Call the Delegate / Invoke like so

showLoadingPicInvoke(0, oldform) ' 0 is just a variable used in the del / invoke method you don't have to have them can remove, oldform ( origional form passed to the Thread is a must.)

```
Delegate Sub changeText(oldform As Form1)
Sub changeTextInvoke(ByVal oldform As Form1)
    If oldform.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New changeText(AddressOf changeTextInvoke)
        oldform.ControlName.Invoke(d, New Object() {oldform})
    Else
```

Below is where you change to do what you want on the Form1 ( Main Form ).vb

```
            'changeText
            'oldform.ControlName.value = value
            'oldform.ControlName.Refresh()


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I did already to see the result, but I dont want to bother the user all the time, I want something like the statusbar the outlook, where you can see "Sending message 1 out of XXX"...without overloading the rest of the system..

Comment: @AsuncionCarreigos http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13547/An-Office-2003-like-popup-notifier , get one here - download the control :P that should do the trick

Comment: This code looks fine,but I don't want to complicate myself too much. I just want to change the ToolstripStatusLabel text property from a thread..

Comment: Edited the Answer to include a del/invoke example to change something on main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found a solution to it, which is passing the label as a parameter of the function inside the thread, as this:

BulkThread = New Thread(Sub() ProcessBulkList(ToolStripStatusLabel1)) 
BulkThread.Start()

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke` on a `Delegate` dynamically invokes the delegate on the *same* thread. There is no cross-thread messaging involved. To update the GUI, the update needs to be done from the thread which created the control you are modifying (i.e. the main thread). You need to use the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method on the `Control` to run your code on the proper thread. These methods are implementations of `ISynchronizeInvoke`, and marshal the call to the proper thread.

Comment: The control (label in this case) is already created in the MDI form before I run the thread to send the emails, so how I am supposed to do that??? Any idea??

Comment: Read my post again. Just call `MDI.LabelSMS.Invoke` to call a method which sets the label instead of setting the label directly.

Comment: Sorry I didnt say that the Label is on the StatusStrip bar on the bottom, so I can not access the invoke method (I dunno why BTW..)

Comment: Ok so I cannot access the invoke method because is not a Control...I´ve been reading about it but I dont really understand how to get it done... someone said to invoke the statusstrip instead but....no clue how to proceed...

If I am in a thread already, how I am supposed to invoke the statuststrip???